# Remove space between value and units. SASS

Tags: sass, space

A SCSS function written for converting pixel to rem generates a space between value and unit. How to avoid the space. Details mentioned in the URL give below.

jsfiddle domain + /9pe5a1kx/1/

Comment: Where is the url? Why do you link the core of the question to an external source?

Comment: Please post your code here

Comment: Hi.. thanks for considering.. 
There was an issue posting code and URL so I chose this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function:

```
@function px2em($px, $metric: 'em', $base-font-size: 16px) {
  @if unitless($px) {
    @warn "Assuming #{$px} to be in pixels, attempting to convert it into pixels.";
    @return px2em($px * 1px, $metric, $base-font-size);
  } @else if unit($px) == em {
    @return $px;
  }
  @return #{($px / $base-font-size) + $metric};
}
```